# yum update breaks CentOS

Tags: ssh, centos, yum

There is a CentOS 7 VPS. I just tried to follow [guide to install php 7.4](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-7-4-on-centos-7/), and ran

```
sudo yum update
```

It did stuff, outputted a list of "install" lines, and then a list of "clean" lines, as I remember, like

```
clean something (82/82)
```

Comes to 82, and seems to hang, *it did not exit*, although input was working. I tried to enter exit, sudo exit, sudo reboot, but it just entered and no result.

Earlier I set up Apache, ssl, all worked. I rebooted VPS, and now my site does not work as from domain as from IP. It says connection refused.

I also now can't connect via ssh (timeout error), but can connect via VNC.

Ssh stopped work before reboot - when in current powershell window with ssh session hanged (i.e. hanged yum update command, as I described above), I closed powershell, and opened new one, but already could not connect.

Can my server be restored?

Update

Try to follow [this one answe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458244/centos-7-sshd-seems-not-to-work)r. Is this output ok?

[output of sudo firewall-cmd  --list-all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsKsj.png) ,

```
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

Says that it is active

**Update 2**

Seems like I removed ssh service in firewall. Now I reinstalled firewall, added ssh, and I can connect via ssh.

But I still get connection refused, trying to open site in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, there was two issues:

1. SSH - Following [Digitalocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/additional-recommended-steps-for-new-centos-7-servers) on firewall setup, I just copied all commands, without reading the descriptions and run command that blocks ssh with firewall. I reinstalled firewall, setup it again, without calling that command and now can connect via ssh.
2. HTTP - seems like I just skipped command to run httpd on boot:   `sudo systemctl enable httpd.service`

Now all works. Why it broke on `yum update` I do not know for sure.